# Wildfly 13 having wrong version of Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

I have following Maven dependency in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

A) When running it on wildfly-13.0.0.Final on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-119-generic x86_64) with Java 1.8.0_171, it is complaining about a missing method in the Guava library (which is a Guava version < 20.0):

```
2018-07-23 10:43:21,718 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-182) Exception in thread "Thread-182" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
2018-07-23 10:43:21,718 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-182)     at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:380)
2018-07-23 10:43:21,719 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-182)     at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
2018-07-23 10:43:21,719 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-182)     at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ops.factory.DefaultOpFactory.<init>(DefaultOpFactory.java:71)
2018-07-23 10:43:21,719 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-182)     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
2018-07-23 10:43:21,719 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-182)     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
2018-07-23 10:43:21,719 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-182)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
2018-07-23 10:43:21,719 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-182)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
2018-07-23 10:43:21,719 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-182)     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
2018-07-23 10:43:21,719 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-182)     at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.initWithBackend(Nd4j.java:6192)
2018-07-23 10:43:21,720 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-182)     at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.initContext(Nd4j.java:6087)
2018-07-23 10:43:21,720 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-182)     at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.<clinit>(Nd4j.java:201)
2018-07-23 10:43:21,720 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-182)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

B) It runs on Mac OS X 10.13.5 with Java 1.8.0_144 without errors.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not complaining about a missing dependency...it looks the version which is using is different...

Comment: But why does it use a different version?

Comment: I assume you have another version in some of your transitive dependencies...try via `mvn dependency:tree` ...

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree` returned a list containing `[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile`